# Does normal paper currency contain enough narcotics residue to attract a drug-sniffing dog?

Tags: recreational-drugs, law-enforcement, dogs, currency

It seems pretty well established that paper currency (e.g. in the US) is commonly contaminated with trace amounts of cocaine or other illegal narcotics.  (See [Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/cocaine-on-money/) for instance, though I'm happy to have this assumption challenged.)  Is this contamination sufficient to attract alerts by drug detection dogs?

[Wikipedia says yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Contaminated_currency&oldid=867469113): "The drug content is too low for prosecution but not too low to trigger response to drug-sniffing dogs".  But their citation is to a [newspaper article](https://www.sfgate.com/news/article/Supreme-Court-expands-police-search-powers-2703144.php) that makes no mention of money or currency.

[This 1998 Slate article](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/1998/12/is-there-cocaine-on-your-money.html) says: "In 1994, a U.S. Circuit Court held that ordinary money contains enough cocaine to attract a drug-sniffing dog."  They don't give a reference to the case, but I think it might be [*US v. Florez*](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/871/1411/1685213/); however, the court's opinion only seems to say that the defense *claimed* this was true (note 12), and doesn't seem to come to a conclusion as to whether it actually is.  There is also [*US v $30,060 in US Currency*](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1994107839f3d10391908), in which the court found that a dog's alert on currency is not evidence that the possessor is somehow involved with narcotics, partly due to the fact that money is commonly contaminated.  But this seems like a somewhat different question and a different standard of proof, and anyway I'm not inclined to consider judges as scientific experts.

On the other hand, the [American Society of Canine Trainers](http://www.asctk9.org/id54.html) says that "currency in circulation does not contain enough narcotic scent for a narcotic detector dog to alert to", and they also cite case law in their favor.

What data actually supports any of these claims?  Does currency commonly contain enough narcotics residue to trigger an alert by a typical drug detection dog, at a rate significantly higher than the usual rate of false positives for such dogs?

[I became interested in this claim after it appeared in [this travel.SE answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126625/1362).  Thanks RoboKaren, even though you're not a notable source by yourself.]

Comment: The police pups were introduced here 10 ish years ago to combat GHB, which has no odour https://www.police.vic.gov.au/retrievemedia.asp?Media_ID=35809

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Given that a plastic bag ought to literally prevent anyone from being able to smell the product (smell is small samples of the material flowing through the air, and plastic is a pretty good barrier!) that makes a lot of sense. Dogs have an amazing sense of smell (so small contaminations, small leaks in the plastic, okay maybe) but I always thought the notion of magical sniffer dogs to be a bit dodgy.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: Doesn't match up with customs at airports (successfully) using sniffer dogs to detect drugs in a room full of suitcases. I don't say that dogs *don't* react to (subconscious) cues from their handlers, I just say that dogs are perfectly capable of sniffing out drugs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: 1) One layer of plastic sheet isn't a good olfactory barrier, when you're talking about a dog's sense of smell. 2) Avoiding outside contamination when doing the packaging is extremely difficult. -- Next time you prepare food for the deep freeze, try smelling the plastic bag. I'm able to smell a Bolognese through a closed Tupperware box, and I'm not a sniffer dog... ;-)

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10071-010-0373-2 popped up on some other forum, again not directly an answer but in a trial 85% of the time a dog and handler team made a false alert.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm no expert but I think drugs are wrapped in more than a single plastic sheet or a tupperware box :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And even multiple layers of cling film still have all the problems mentioned. I just wanted to point out that it's not true that "a plastic bag ought to literally prevent anyone from being able to smell the product". The same procedures (or lack thereof) that make traceable amounts of cocaine show up on dollar bills (contamination) makes them show up on the outside of those packages, which is why they're e.g. hidden in coffee or otherwise "masked". Because dogs can sniff them out. Trying to avoid any conspiracy / harassment theory springing up here.

Comment: metalized mylar bags or turkey bags apparently stop bears smelling food, but then they might hear the rustle

Comment: I'll note that there is no such thing as "normal" paper currency.  One wad might be 30 years old, but taken out of the drawer of an old miser.  Another wad might have been in the pocket with an out-and-out drug dealer for several days, or possibly even in the drug satchel.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not saying that they can't, just that their effectiveness is lower than what most people expect *especially* when they go around looking for people to sniff because at that point the (unconscious) cues that the handler (or the person examined) gives trump any cues from the odor. So I'm pretty sure that very few people got caught red handed solely due to the odor of the drugs. Also: there's plenty of cases where K9 units failed to find big amounts of drugs in suitcases/cars etc. In the end: better than nothing but they cannot be trusted. That's why you have scanners at airports.

Comment: @DevSolar tupperware lids hardly make a proper seal, nor does cling film. I would expect even a simple LD-polyethylene bag to contain odours much better, if it's properly weld-sealed and the outside then scrubbed with alcohol and detergents – which seems a reasonable enough thing to do for all but the most careless smugglers.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta The problem is most handlers aren't careful enough to avoid teaching the dog to alert when the handler thinks there are drugs.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: That would be pretty shoddy training, then. The training I've seen (documentaries about), the drill is done "double-blind", i.e. the handler doesn't know where the drugs are either. Exactly so the dog cannot "pick up" anything from the handler in training, and thus won't go for "handler cues" in the field either. Perhaps a separate question?

Comment: @DevSolar The problem isn't with the initial training, but with what happens afterwards.

Comment: @DevSolar Even if the handler is honest, its easy for the dog to pick up unconscious non-verbal cues.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans. And of course there is no way to distinguish between an honest and dishonest handler unless you happen to capture an obvious cue to the dog on video.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Did you miss the part where *the handler does not know where the training contraband is, either?*

Comment: I want to guess that the answer is "yes." In your "on the other hand" citation, there was the following paragraph: "currency sniffs are the only area where a positive canine alert is not probable cause. It is a reasonable suspicion factor or “strong evidence.”" If we drug-sniffing dogs cannot sniff normal currency, then a positive canine alert WOULD be probably cause, unlike the paragraph.

Comment: Also, see https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1556-4029.13755  . "It is concluded that canine alert to U.S. currency is not sufficiently reliable to determine that currency was directly used in an illicit drug transaction." For this to be the case, false positives have to occur (i.e. drug-sniffing dogs alerting normal currency). The false alert rate for heroin is 17.7% (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24631776).

Answer (score 4):

**Evidence:**

1. Research has shown that drug detection dogs act routinely based on the behavioral cues of their handlers, rather than only acting on their sense of smell for odor detection.

   > In conclusion, these findings confirm that handler beliefs affect working dog outcomes, and human indication of scent location affects distribution of alerts more than dog interest in a particular location. These findings emphasize the importance of understanding both human and human–dog social cognitive factors in applied situations.
   >   [**Source: Handler beliefs affect scent detection dog outcomes**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10071-010-0373-2)
2. Research has also showed that some of the high odor compounds are not used in the manufacture of training scents used in training drug detection dogs which might lead to failure of detection of those drugs.

   > A small number of volatile and semi-volatile compounds present in very low concentrations and associated with very low odor detection thresholds cause the characteristic smell of a drug. These high odor impact compounds are not being used to manufacture surrogate training scents used in training forensic canines. This omission could explain why these surrogate scents are generally not effective. This information could lead to increased understanding of what drug detection canines are using as the signature odor of street drugs. [**Source: Investigating the aroma of marijuana, cocaine, and heroin for forensic applications using simultaneous multidimensional gas chromatography - mass spectrometry - olfactometry**](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/etd/14638/)
3. Various factors such as breed type, drug type and searching environment type might influence drug detection performance in drug detector dogs.

   > The olfactory acuity of dogs’ sense of smell toward various volatile chemical compounds may differ considerably, though results may also reflect different experimental designs of different laboratories. Odors of different drugs may be differently sensed by dogs, and consequently ease of detection may differ. These differences may be related to polymorphic forms of olfactory receptor genes or their breed specific allelic variants or to the proportion of functional vs. non-functional genes showing affinity to the volatile chemical compounds characteristic of a drug. It is well known that scent detection dog performance depends not only on olfactory acuity but also on canine cognitive and learning abilities. The detection performance of sniffer dogs is context-dependent.
   >   [**Source: Efficacy of drug detection by fully-trained police dogs varies by breed, training level, type of drug and search environment**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0379073814000371)

**TL;DR:**

Based on current research, microgram levels of cocaine present on circulated US currency is insufficient to draw an alert from drug detector dogs.

> The authors concluded that as the average level of cocaine present in a single bill (10 lg) is 100,000 less than the average level required for drug-detector canine alert (1 g), “it is not plausible that innocently-contaminated US currency contains sufficiently enough quantities [sic] of cocaine and associated volatile chemicals to signal an alert from a properly-train drug detector dog.”.
>   [S**ource: Drug Contamination of U.S. Paper Currency and Forensic Relevance of Canine Alert to Paper Currency: A Critical Review of the Scientific Literature**](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1556-4029.13755).

However there are only two published experimental studies on drug-detector dog alerts to U.S. currency spiked with various amounts of cocaine for the above comment and more research is needed to drawn an conclusion whether normal US paper currency contains enough narcotics residue to attract a drug-sniffing dog.

Comment: @BarryHarrison-The TL;DR source contains the complete literature review on US paper currency drug contamination and drug detection dog alerts. I think I have included all the important research for evidence.